# Use of lit() in expr()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

The line:

```
df.withColumn("test", expr("concat(lon, lat)"))
```

works as expected but

```
df.withColumn("test", expr("concat(lon, lit(','), lat)"))
```

produces the following exception:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'lit'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 12
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$LookupFunctions$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$applyOrElse$49.apply(Analyzer.scala:1198)

Why? And what would be the workaround?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The string argument to [`expr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#expr-java.lang.String-) will be parsed as a SQL expression and used to construct a column. Since [`lit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#lit-java.lang.Object-) is not a valid SQL command this will give you an error. (`lit` is used in Spark to convert a literal value into a new column.)

To solve this, simply remove the `lit` part:

```
df.withColumn("test", expr("concat(lon, ',', lat)"))
```

Or use the in-built Spark [`concat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) function directly without `expr`:

```
df.withColumn("test", concat($"lon", lit(","), $"lat"))
```

Since `concat` takes columns as arguments `lit` must be used here.

Comment: But how to write the following using `expr`?  
`df.withColumn("test", concat($"lon", lit(" a nonColumn string")) `

Comment: @MehrdadAP: When using `expr` to concat a constant string you can simply use single quotes. The equivalent of the example using `expr` would be: `df.withColumn("test", expr("concat(lon, ' a nonColumn string')"))`.